# LINQ Query - Group multiple entities and sum

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, sum

I am trying to convert SQL Query to LINQ

Here is the relevant model:

```
public class GISTracts 
{ 
    public int? LeaseID     { get; set; } 
    public int? TractID     { get; set; } 
    public string County    { get; set; } 
    public string Source    { get; set; } 
    public string Legal     { get; set; } 
    public decimal? Net     { get; set; } 
    public string TractName { get; set; } 
    public decimal? GrossAc { get; set; } 
    public decimal? GasExecutive { get; set; } 
}
```

Here is my sql query:

```
select leaseId, Tracts.Id as TractsId, Tracts.Name as TractsName, Tracts.GrossAc, County, Source,  District, Legal,
Sum(Interests.GasExecutive*Tracts.GrossAc) as Net
from WorkingInterestGroups
Inner Join Interests on WorkingInterestGroups.Id = Interests.WorkingInterestGroupId
Inner Join Tracts on Interests.TractId = Tracts.Id
group by leaseId, Tracts.Id , Tracts.Name, Tracts.GrossAc, County, District, Legal, Source;
```

Here is my LINQ Query

```
var myResults = from WIG in db.WorkingInterestGroups
                join In in db.Interests on WIG.Id equals In.WorkingInterestGroupId
                join Tr in db.Tracts on In.TractId equals Tr.Id
                where WIG.LeaseId == LeaseID
                group WIG by new
                {
                    WIG.LeaseId,
                    Tr.Id,
                    Tr.Name,
                    Tr.GrossAc,
                    Tr.County,
                    Tr.District,
                    Tr.Legal,
                    Tr.Source                                
                } into gcs
                select new GISTracts
                {
                    LeaseID = gcs.Key.LeaseId,
                    TractID = gcs.Key.Id,
                    TractName = gcs.Key.Name,
                    GrossAc = gcs.Key.GrossAc,
                    County = gcs.Key.County,
                    Source = gcs.Key.Source,
                    Legal = gcs.Key.Legal,
                    Net = gcs.Sum(x=>x.GrossAcres * x.Interests.GasExecutive)
                };
```

Unable to get Net Field in select statement in my LINQ query.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Unable to get Net Field in select statement in my LINQ query" But it's there, isn't it? Do you mean that some error occurs or that you don't get the expected results?

Comment: Your code seems correct, can you add your models so we can have more details.

Comment: `public class GISTracts
    {
        public int? LeaseID { get; set; }
        public int? TractID { get; set; }
        public string TractName { get; set; }
        public decimal? GrossAc { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string Legal { get; set; }
        public decimal? GasExecutive { get; set; }
        public decimal? Net { get; set; }
    } `

Comment: Error goes off if I use                                                                                         Net = gcs.Sum(x => x.GrossAcres * x.Interests.Sum(j=>j.GasExecutive)). But Net is not same as SQL query results

Comment: "Error goes off" -- Which error? What you do here is seen more often in Stack Overflow questions. You tell what you want and what you tried, fine, but apparently it didn't succeed and you forget to tell why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is, you haven't included `Tracts` entity in `group` clause. Try
updating the `group by` clause as -

```
group new { WIG,In,Tr } by new {....} into gcs
```

instead of

```
group WIG by new {....} into gcs
```

Then update the Net calculation as

```
Net = gcs.Sum(x=>x.Tr.GrossAcres * x.In.GasExecutive) //Not sure if GrossAcres part of tracks or other entity, update it accordingly.
```

Your `linq` query will look like below.

```
var myResults = from WIG in db.WorkingInterestGroups
                            join In in db.Interests on WIG.Id equals In.WorkingInterestGroupId
                            join Tr in db.Tracts on In.TractId equals Tr.Id
                            where WIG.LeaseId == LeaseID
                            group new { WIG,In,Tr } by new
                            {
                                WIG.LeaseId,
                                Tr.Id,
                                Tr.Name,
                                Tr.GrossAc,
                                Tr.County,
                                Tr.District,
                                Tr.Legal,
                                Tr.Source                                
                            } into gcs
                            select new GISTracts
                            {
                                LeaseID = gcs.Key.LeaseId,
                                TractID = gcs.Key.Id,
                                TractName = gcs.Key.Name,
                                GrossAc = gcs.Key.GrossAc,
                                County = gcs.Key.County,
                                Source = gcs.Key.Source,
                                Legal = gcs.Key.Legal,
                                Net = gcs.Sum(x=>x.Tr.GrossAcres * x.In.GasExecutive)
                            };
```